# How can i find the root cause of an application hang?

Tags: debugging, freeze, leadtools-sdk

I've done a lot of work over the past many months trying to get a root cause to this issue with a software application. I am not a programmer. I'm an IT Guy with limited software support by no fault of my own (the other side just isn't very responsive, and i'm afraid i'll be in this stalemate with them for years)

This software hangs daily. It is no doubt a software compatibility or dependency issue. I was able to run a process dump and get some information about the hang. It says something about a breakpoint being reached and the associated module being ltkrn13n, a LEADTOOLS dll file that can be found in the root of the folder associated with the program that hangs.

Given this info what would you do as a next step to continue learning what is causing this to happen? That is what i want - i want to know why so maybe i can shine some light on this and get the help i need to get it resolved and maybe learn a thing or two along the way.

Let me know what you would do next.

Comment: Without the details you mention there is no way to know what is going on. An apparent hang can be caused by a huge number of program and operating environment issues. Honestly, even a great developer can;t really do much with a program they don't have the source for. Collect the logs and traces as you have and throw it over the wall to the maintainers of the application. Without source and a specific problem I'm not sure this is a good fit for SO.

Comment: understood - i appreciate the comment! I figured that there wasn't much else that could be done by me but i was curious about the investigation piece to really know if i have done all that i could to gather info. Thanks!